# localhost and phpmyadmin load blank pages

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I just installed WAMP server 2.0i on my laptop which has XP SP3 newly installed a couple of days ago.

However, when I try to access phpmyadmin or load the localhost page all I get is a blank page in both cases. The MySQL console works fine.

WAMP used to work fine on my previous XP installation, though I am sure the OS doesnt have much to do with WAMP..

Any pointers to get it working back again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be carefull, Skype is listening on port 80. It displays a blank screen to localhost.

Go to skype option menu and disable this option.
File -> Options -> Connection -> Uncheck "Use port 80 as an alternative for..."

Comment: AWESOME..!! Never could have spotted Skype as the culprit..!! Thanks..!

Comment: left click WAMP icon in notification area, select apache then apache service then select test port 80. this will tell you what's causing the conflict.